# Clean up querystring on request in Struts

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1 and only want clean the URL of parameters on each request.

In the request, for example:

```
myapp.com/view.do?method=search
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{      
request.setAttribute("RESULT","PERU");
return mapping.findForward("home");
}
```

In the forward, the URL is the same

```
myapp.com/view.do?method=search
```

Later, I do this:

```
public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{      
request.setAttribute("RESULT","PERU");
ActionForward af = new ActionForward(mapping.findForward("home"));
af.setRedirect(true);
return af;
}
```

I get the URL: `myapp.com/home.jsp`, fine!!! But, I lose the attribute `"RESULT"`.

When I use `setRedirect()` Struts 1 make a new request, lose all attributes.

Any other form of clean up the URL in the `ActionForward`?

Comment: Look into url rewriting, like for example with Tuckey Rewrite filter. Basically you're looking at the problem backwards I think.

Comment: I not want implement Tuckey, only want make the change in the ActionForward.

Comment: You're redirecting, which tells the browser to make a *new request*, so anything in the request will be lost.

Comment: @YanOner, Like I said, you're looking at it backwards. What you should do is: Instead of using a oldschool query string and trying to "clean it up" into a pretty url, use a pretty url and rewriting to forward to the oldschool query string in the back end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the page to home you can simply return the `mapping.findForward("home")` like the following

```
public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{      
    request.setAttribute("RESULT","PERU");


    return mapping.findForward("home");
}
```

Comment: But, this not clean up the QueryString of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Save attributes to the session before you make redirect

```
public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {      
  request.getSession().setAttribute("RESULT","PERU");
  ActionForward af = new ActionForward(mapping.findForward("home"));
  af.setRedirect(true);
  return af;
}
```

Comment: The problem of this, the others methods would have that clean up the attribute in session, is very cumbersome. I think, I'll have that modify the URL on the load of jsp.

Comment: Other methods should use their own request attributes, until they want to redirect the request.